# Monkey patching a module function depending on another function inside the module

Tags: python

I have a function inside a module that is broken

broken.py

```
def brokenfunc():
    dependency()


def dependency():
    print "hello"
```

The routine depends on another function dependency, which is fine. I need to monkey patch broken, so in another module I did

patched.py

```
import broken

def brokenfunc():
    print "patched"

    dependency()

brokenfunc.__globals__["dependency"]=broken.brokenfunc.__globals__["dependency"]
broken.brokenfunc = brokenfunc

broken.brokenfunc()
```

Clearly, I have to override the globals because the dependency in the patched function is defined in the patched module and would look for dependency there.

This works, but I am unsatisfied with the hack. I tried to update the whole globals dictionary, but in that case I override too much and the broken function keeps runnning. Is this the correct way of doing it (considering also corner cases) or there's another, correct strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just reference the dependency in your new function:

```
import broken

def brokenfunc():
    print "patched"

    broken.dependency()

broken.brokenfunc = brokenfunc
```

or you can add `dependency` to your module globals by import:

```
import broken
from broken import dependency

def brokenfunc():
    print "patched"

    dependency()

broken.brokenfunc = brokenfunc
```

There is really no need to go to such lengths; `brokenfunc.__globals__` is *just your current module namespace*.

Comment: Yep. Today I won the "How to make my life more complicated" prize

Comment: except my reason for overriding in `__globals__` is mocking. are there any corner-cases I should be aware of? (disclaimer: I've tried `mock` and `minimock`, but they didn't work out as I wished, so I do it manually instead). [Data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) has it that *the attribute* (the reference itself) is read only.

Comment: Why the insistence on accessing `__globals__` though? There are more readable ways to accessing a module namespace, even dynamically. And try harder with `mock`, instead.

Comment: I guess it may not be the module namespace, in case of nested def, as in terming it nonlocal. But you have a point, and I don't know the dynamic way.

Comment: @naxa: Nested functions are not so easily patched. See [Can you patch \*just\* a nested function with closure, or must the whole outer function be repeated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27550228)

Comment: If I then do `from broken import brokenfunc`, will it be the patched one or original one?

Comment: @JacksonTale: that depends; you need to make sure that that import runs **after** the monkey patching has taken place. `brokenfunc` is a new global name referencing whatever `broken.brokenfunc` referenced at the time that `from broken import brokenfunc` ran.