# Can you patch *just* a nested function with closure, or must the whole outer function be repeated?

Tags: python, closures, monkeypatching

A 3rd party library we use contains a rather long function that uses a nested function inside it. Our use of that library triggers a bug in that function, and we very much would like to solve that bug.

Unfortunately, the library maintainers are somewhat slow with fixes, but we don't want to have to fork the library. We also cannot hold our release until they have fixed the issue.

We would prefer to use monkey-patching to fix this issue here as that is easier to track than patching the source. However, to repeat a very large function where just replacing the inner function would be enough feels overkill, and makes it harder for others to see what exactly we changed. Are we stuck with a static patch to the library egg?

The inner function relies on closing over a variable; a contrived example would be:

```
def outerfunction(*args):
    def innerfunction(val):
        return someformat.format(val)

    someformat = 'Foo: {}'
    for arg in args:
        yield innerfunction(arg)
```

where we would want to replace just the implementation of `innerfunction()`. The actual outer function is far, far longer. We'd reuse the closed-over variable and maintain the function signature, of course.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Yes**, you can replace an inner function, even if it is using a closure. You'll have to jump through a few hoops though. Please take into account:

1. You need to create the replacement function as a nested function too, to ensure that Python creates the same closure. If the original function has a closure over the names `foo` and `bar`, you need to define your replacement as a nested function with the same names closed over. More importantly, you need to use those names *in the same order*; closures are referenced by index.
2. Monkey patching is always fragile and can break with the implementation changing. This is no exception. Retest your monkey patch whenever you change versions of the patched library.

### Code objects

To understand how this will work, I'll first explain how Python handles nested functions. Python uses *code objects* to produce function objects as needed. Each code object has an associated constants sequence, and the code objects for nested functions are stored in that sequence:

```
>>> def outerfunction(*args):
...     def innerfunction(val):
...         return someformat.format(val)
...     someformat = 'Foo: {}'
...     for arg in args:
...         yield innerfunction(arg)
... 
>>> outerfunction.__code__
<code object outerfunction at 0x105b27ab0, file "<stdin>", line 1>
>>> outerfunction.__code__.co_consts
(None, <code object innerfunction at 0x10f136ed0, file "<stdin>", line 2>, 'outerfunction.<locals>.innerfunction', 'Foo: {}')
```

The `co_consts` sequence is an immutable object, a tuple, so we cannot just swap out the inner code object. I'll show later on how we'll produce a new function object with *just* that code object replaced.

### How closures are handled

Next, we need to cover closures. At compile time, Python determines that
a) `someformat` is not a local name in `innerfunction` and that
b) it is closing over the same name in `outerfunction`.
Python not only then generates the bytecode to produce the correct name lookups, the code objects for both the nested and the outer functions are annotated to record that `someformat` is to be closed over:

```
>>> outerfunction.__code__.co_cellvars
('someformat',)
>>> outerfunction.__code__.co_consts[1].co_freevars
('someformat',)
```

You want to make sure that the replacement inner code object only ever lists those same names as free variables, and does so in the same order.

Closures are created at run-time; the byte-code to produce them is part of the outer function:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(outerfunction)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (someformat)
              2 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object innerfunction at 0x10f136ed0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('outerfunction.<locals>.innerfunction')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (innerfunction)

# ... rest of disassembly omitted ...
```

The `LOAD_CLOSURE` bytecode there creates a closure for the `someformat` variable; Python creates as many closures as used by the function *in the order they are first used in the inner function*. This is an important fact to remember for later. The function itself looks up these closures by position:

```
>>> dis.dis(outerfunction.__code__.co_consts[1])
  3           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (someformat)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (format)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (val)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `LOAD_DEREF` opcode picked the closure at position `0` here to gain access to the `someformat` closure.

In theory this also means you can use entirely different names for the closures in your inner function, but for debugging purposes it makes much more sense to stick to the same names. It also makes verifying that the replacement function will slot in properly easier, as you can just compare the `co_freevars` tuples if you use the same names.

### `replace_inner_function()`

Now for the swapping trick. Functions are objects like any other in Python, instances of a specific type. The type isn't exposed normally, but the `type()` call still returns it. The same applies to code objects, and both types even have documentation:

```
>>> type(outerfunction)
<type 'function'>
>>> print(type(outerfunction).__doc__)
Create a function object.

  code
    a code object
  globals
    the globals dictionary
  name
    a string that overrides the name from the code object
  argdefs
    a tuple that specifies the default argument values
  closure
    a tuple that supplies the bindings for free variables
>>> type(outerfunction.__code__)
<type 'code'>
>>> print(type(outerfunction.__code__).__doc__)
code(argcount, posonlyargcount, kwonlyargcount, nlocals, stacksize,
      flags, codestring, constants, names, varnames, filename, name,
      firstlineno, lnotab[, freevars[, cellvars]])

Create a code object.  Not for the faint of heart.
```

(The exact argument count and docstring varies between Python versions; Python 3.0 added the `kwonlyargcount` argument, and as of Python 3.8, posonlyargcount has been added).

We'll use these type objects to produce a new `code` object with updated constants, and then a new function object with updated code object; the following function is compatible with Python versions 2.7 through to 3.8.

```
def replace_inner_function(outer, new_inner):
    """Replace a nested function code object used by outer with new_inner

    The replacement new_inner must use the same name and must at most use the
    same closures as the original.

    """
    if hasattr(new_inner, '__code__'):
        # support both functions and code objects
        new_inner = new_inner.__code__

    # find original code object so we can validate the closures match
    ocode = outer.__code__
    function, code = type(outer), type(ocode)
    iname = new_inner.co_name
    orig_inner = next(
        const for const in ocode.co_consts
        if isinstance(const, code) and const.co_name == iname)

    # you can ignore later closures, but since they are matched by position
    # the new sequence must match the start of the old.
    assert (orig_inner.co_freevars[:len(new_inner.co_freevars)] ==
            new_inner.co_freevars), 'New closures must match originals'

    # replace the code object for the inner function
    new_consts = tuple(
        new_inner if const is orig_inner else const
        for const in outer.__code__.co_consts)

    # create a new code object with the new constants
    try:
        # Python 3.8 added code.replace(), so much more convenient!
        ncode = ocode.replace(co_consts=new_consts)
    except AttributeError:
        # older Python versions, argument counts vary so we need to check
        # for specifics.
        args = [
            ocode.co_argcount, ocode.co_nlocals, ocode.co_stacksize,
            ocode.co_flags, ocode.co_code,
            new_consts,  # replacing the constants
            ocode.co_names, ocode.co_varnames, ocode.co_filename,
            ocode.co_name, ocode.co_firstlineno, ocode.co_lnotab,
            ocode.co_freevars, ocode.co_cellvars,
        ]
        if hasattr(ocode, 'co_kwonlyargcount'):
            # Python 3+, insert after co_argcount
            args.insert(1, ocode.co_kwonlyargcount)
        # Python 3.8 adds co_posonlyargcount, but also has code.replace(), used above
        ncode = code(*args)

    # and a new function object using the updated code object
    return function(
        ncode, outer.__globals__, outer.__name__,
        outer.__defaults__, outer.__closure__
    )
```

The above function validates that the new inner function (which can be passed in as either a code object or as a function) will indeed use the same closures as the original. It then creates new code and function objects to match the old `outer` function object, but with the nested function (located by name) replaced with your monkey patch.

### Let's try it out

To demonstrate that the above all works, lets replace `innerfunction` with one that increments each formatted value by 2:

```
>>> def create_inner():
...     someformat = None  # the actual value doesn't matter
...     def innerfunction(val):
...         return someformat.format(val + 2)
...     return innerfunction
... 
>>> new_inner = create_inner()
```

The new inner function is created as a nested function too; this is important as it ensures that Python will use the correct bytecode to look up the `someformat` closure. I used a `return` statement to extract the function object, but you could also look at `create_inner.__code__.co_consts` to grab the code object.

Now we can patch the original outer function, swapping out *just* the inner function:

```
>>> new_outer = replace_inner_function(outerfunction, new_inner)
>>> list(outerfunction(6, 7, 8))
['Foo: 6', 'Foo: 7', 'Foo: 8']
>>> list(new_outer(6, 7, 8))
['Foo: 8', 'Foo: 9', 'Foo: 10']
```

The original function echoed out the original values, but the new returned values incremented by 2.

You can even create new replacement inner functions that use *fewer* closures:

```
>>> def demo_outer():
...     closure1 = 'foo'
...     closure2 = 'bar'
...     def demo_inner():
...         print(closure1, closure2)
...     demo_inner()
...
>>> def create_demo_inner():
...     closure1 = None
...     def demo_inner():
...         print(closure1)
...
>>> replace_inner_function(demo_outer, create_demo_inner.__code__.co_consts[1])()
foo
```

### In a nutshell

So, to complete the picture:

1. Create your monkey-patch inner function as a nested function with the same closures in the same order.
2. Use the above `replace_inner_function()` to produce a *new* outer function.
3. Monkey patch the original outer function to use the new outer function produced in step 2.

Answer (score 23):

Martijn's answer is good, but there is one drawback that would be nice to remove:

> You want to make sure that the replacement inner code object only ever lists those same names as free variables, and does so in the same order.

This isn't a particularly difficult constraint for the normal case, but it isn't pleasant to be dependent on undefined behaviours like name ordering and when things go wrong there are potentially really nasty errors and possibly even hard crashes.

My approach has its own drawbacks, but in most cases I believe the drawback above would motivate using it. As far as I can tell, it should also be more portable.

The basic approach is to load the source with `inspect.getsource`, change it and then evaluate it. This is done at AST level in order to keep things in order.

Here is the code:

```
import ast
import inspect
import sys

class AstReplaceInner(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, replacement):
        self.replacement = replacement

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        if node.name == self.replacement.name:
            # Prevent the replacement AST from messing
            # with the outer AST's line numbers
            return ast.copy_location(self.replacement, node)

        self.generic_visit(node)
        return node

def ast_replace_inner(outer, inner, name=None):
    if name is None:
        name = inner.__name__

    outer_ast = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(outer))
    inner_ast = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(inner))

    # Fix the source lines for the outer AST
    outer_ast = ast.increment_lineno(outer_ast, inspect.getsourcelines(outer)[1] - 1)

    # outer_ast should be a module so it can be evaluated;
    # inner_ast should be a function so we strip the module node
    inner_ast = inner_ast.body[0]

    # Replace the function
    inner_ast.name = name
    modified_ast = AstReplaceInner(inner_ast).visit(outer_ast)

    # Evaluate the modified AST in the original module's scope
    compiled = compile(modified_ast, inspect.getsourcefile(outer), "exec")
    outer_globals = outer.__globals__ if sys.version_info >= (3,) else outer.func_globals
    exec_scope = {}

    exec(compiled, outer_globals, exec_scope)
    return exec_scope.popitem()[1]
```

A quick walkthrough. `AstReplaceInner` is an `ast.NodeTransformer`, which just allows you to modify ASTs by mapping certain nodes to certain other nodes. In this case, it takes a `replacement` node to replace an `ast.FunctionDef` node with whenever names match.

`ast_replace_inner` is the function we really care about, which takes two functions and optionally a name. The name is used to allow replacing the inner function with another function of a different name.

The ASTs are parsed:

```
    outer_ast = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(outer))
    inner_ast = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(inner))
```

The transformation is made:

```
    modified_ast = AstReplaceInner(inner_ast).visit(outer_ast)
```

The code is evaluated and the function extracted:

```
    exec(compiled, outer_globals, exec_scope)
    return exec_scope.popitem()[1]
```

Here's an example of use. Assume this old code is in `buggy.py`:

```
def outerfunction():
    numerator = 10.0

    def innerfunction(denominator):
        return denominator / numerator

    return innerfunction
```

You want to replace `innerfunction` with

```
def innerfunction(denominator):
    return numerator / denominator
```

You write:

```
import buggy

def innerfunction(denominator):
    return numerator / denominator

buggy.outerfunction = ast_replace_inner(buggy.outerfunction, innerfunction)
```

Alternatively, you could write:

```
def divide(denominator):
    return numerator / denominator

buggy.outerfunction = ast_replace_inner(buggy.outerfunction, divide, "innerfunction")
```

The main disadvantage of this technique is that one requires `inspect.getsource` to work on both the target and replacement. This will fail if the target is "built-in" (written in C) or compiled to bytecode before distributing. Note that if it's built-in, Martijn's technique will not work either.

Another major disadvantage is that the line numbers from the inner function are completely screwy. This is not a big problem if the inner function is small, but if you have a large inner function this is worth thinking about.

Other disadvantages come from if the function object is not specified in the same way. For example, you could not patch

```
def outerfunction():
    numerator = 10.0

    innerfunction = lambda denominator: denominator / numerator

    return innerfunction
```

the same way; a different AST transformation would be needed.

You should decide which tradeoff makes the most sense for your particular circumstance.

Comment: How does this interact with tracebacks? With the source regenerated, and AST not tracking a filename I suspect that source lines in the patched version will not be correct, especially so when the number of lines has changed. No opportunity to test this right now, but certainly an aspect to consider.

Comment: I was now able to test this; all offsets for the source code for both inner and outer functions are reset to start at 1. This means that all tracebacks will include the wrong source lines altogether. Moreover, the inner function offsets are used against the original file. The same applies to using a debugger. The offsets can be fixed for the outer function, but the code object for the inner function would need to be re-build to point to the correct filename first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have fixed the line numbering for the outer function, which was pretty simple, although as you say there isn't an obvious way to fix it for the inner function. I'll edit the answer to mention the downside.

Answer (score 4):

I needed this, but in a class and python2/3. So I extended @MartijnPieters's solution some

```
import types, inspect, six

def replace_inner_function(outer, new_inner, class_class=None):
    """Replace a nested function code object used by outer with new_inner

    The replacement new_inner must use the same name and must at most use the
    same closures as the original.

    """
    if hasattr(new_inner, '__code__'):
        # support both functions and code objects
        new_inner = new_inner.__code__

    # find original code object so we can validate the closures match
    ocode = outer.__code__

    iname = new_inner.co_name
    orig_inner = next(
        const for const in ocode.co_consts
        if isinstance(const, types.CodeType) and const.co_name == iname)
    # you can ignore later closures, but since they are matched by position
    # the new sequence must match the start of the old.
    assert (orig_inner.co_freevars[:len(new_inner.co_freevars)] ==
            new_inner.co_freevars), 'New closures must match originals'
    # replace the code object for the inner function
    new_consts = tuple(
        new_inner if const is orig_inner else const
        for const in outer.__code__.co_consts)

    if six.PY3:
        new_code = types.CodeType(ocode.co_argcount, ocode.co_kwonlyargcount, ocode.co_nlocals, ocode.co_stacksize,
             ocode.co_flags, ocode.co_code, new_consts, ocode.co_names,
             ocode.co_varnames, ocode.co_filename, ocode.co_name,
             ocode.co_firstlineno, ocode.co_lnotab, ocode.co_freevars,
             ocode.co_cellvars)
    else:
    # create a new function object with the new constants
        new_code = types.CodeType(ocode.co_argcount, ocode.co_nlocals, ocode.co_stacksize,
             ocode.co_flags, ocode.co_code, new_consts, ocode.co_names,
             ocode.co_varnames, ocode.co_filename, ocode.co_name,
             ocode.co_firstlineno, ocode.co_lnotab, ocode.co_freevars,
             ocode.co_cellvars)

    new_function= types.FunctionType(new_code, outer.__globals__, 
                                     outer.__name__, outer.__defaults__,
                                     outer.__closure__)

    if hasattr(outer, '__self__'):
        if outer.__self__ is None:
            if six.PY3:
                return types.MethodType(new_function, outer.__self__, class_class)
            else:
                return types.MethodType(new_function, outer.__self__, outer.im_class)
        else:
            return types.MethodType(new_function, outer.__self__, outer.__self__.__class__)

    return new_function
```

This should now work for functions, bound classmethods and unbound class methods. (The class_class argument is only needed for python3 for unbound methods). Thanks @MartijnPieters for doing most of the work! I never would have figured this out ;)

Comment: You shouldn't be patching bound methods. A method object has a `__func__` attribute, unwrap the method properly before passing it in and you don't need to worry about classes either (which otherwise could be gotten from `type(method.__self__))`. You want to end up with a function object to add to a class, patching that function just once, and not re-patch methods time and again.

Comment: If you also need to support `classmethod` objects, use `ClassObject.__dict__['classmethod_name']` to get the unbound `classmethod` object, access the `__func__` attribute, patch that, then rewrap the result in `classmethod()` before putting it back on the class.

Comment: Also, when `__self__` is `None`, you don't need to pass in a type either, so `MethodType(new_function, None, None)` in Python 3. In fact, I'm not sure when you'd ever have `outer.__self__ is None` being true in Py3 (`classmethod` objects set `__self__` to the class when bound, and function objects are never bound to the class anymore like they were in Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

I love the ideas of the other answers. Here is another approach to change recompile the source code.

The benefit of this approach is that it's relatively easy to code and it's easy for someone who looks at the code to know the exact lines of code that were changed. The drawbacks are: it is very low level and quite fragile if the source code changes even by a tiny bit like an additional empty line.

So if `buggy.py` is the problematic source code:

```
def outerfunction(*args):
    def innerfunction(val):
        return someformat.format(val)

    someformat = 'Foo: {}'
    for arg in args:
        yield innerfunction(arg)
```

We would like to replace the inner function implementation to be `return someformat.format(val * 2)` - i.e. double the sent value. We can do:

```
from _pytest._code import Code
from buggy import outerfunction


def change_function_source_code(func):
    context = getattr(func, "__globals__", {})
    code = Code.from_function(func)
    source = code.source()

    # this part can be made more generic
    # this is where you put the code changes you want
    # for simplicity, I just replaced the third line
    new_body = source.lines[0:2] + \
               ["        return someformat.format(val * 2)"] + \
               source.lines[4:]

    compiled = compile("\n".join(new_body), str(code.path), "exec")
    exec(compiled, context)

    return context[func.__name__]


def test_buggy_function_before_after():
    # before the change
    assert list(outerfunction(6, 7, 8)) == ['Foo: 6', 'Foo: 7', 'Foo: 8']

    # do the source code change in our local module only
    new_outerfunction = change_function_source_code(outerfunction)

    # to change the behaviour of the old function for everyone:
    #   import buggy
    #   change_function_source_code(buggy.outerfunction)

    # after the change - new function changed behaviour, while the old did not
    assert list(new_outerfunction(6, 7, 8)) == ['Foo: 12', 'Foo: 14', 'Foo: 16']
    assert list(outerfunction(6, 7, 8)) == ['Foo: 6', 'Foo: 7', 'Foo: 8']
```

Comment: This requires that the source is available, however.