# Python change local variable of function in runtime from another module

Tags: python, python-2.7

To understand what I'm asking let's take an example:

I have a method *(this function is not mine)* `m` is declared in a class `c`. This method contains about 200 lines. I just want to add an element to the list which is declared inside the function.

```
   class c(object):
        def m(self):
            .....
            .....
            .....
            ls = [1,2,3]
            for l in ls:
                 ......
                 ......
                 ......
                 ......
```

My problem is the list should be `[1,2,3,4]`. I don't want to copy the whole code of the method just to change the `ls` variable and this method is not mine so
if there are some updates later I want to use them.

I tried to see how Python saves the local variable in the function object and I didn't understand how the relation is set.

```
# this tuple is so complicated 
m.__code__.co_consts
```

So is there an easy way to update this variable, or do I have to update it to add an element to the list by analyzing the variable and see where to put the `4` element?

I searched a lot for this problem but I only found a way how to override a inner method (the answer belongs to @Martijn Pieters):

[Override inner method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550228/can-you-patch-just-a-nested-function-with-closure-or-must-the-whole-outer-fun/27550237)

So is there an easy way to just change a variable without having to rewrite the whole code?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change that variable inside that method.  You need to change the method where it is defined.