# Is it possible to patch/mock internal function inside another function with unittest in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

<sub>Looks like it is impossible, but I'll try to ask...</sub>

Let's say I have this function:

```py
def something(x)

  def subsomething(x):
    return 'a' if x == 1 else 'b'

  message = f'the character is {subsomething(x)}'
  return message
```

Is it possible to patch `subsomething`'s return value and set it to `c` without changing `something`?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you patch \*just\* a nested function with closure, or must the whole outer function be repeated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550228/can-you-patch-just-a-nested-function-with-closure-or-must-the-whole-outer-fun)